# Disease spread through checkerboard

Tags: probability, limits, asymptotics, markov-chains, markov-process

Suppose we have an infinite checkerboard (square grid) with a single “infected” square at time $t=0$. After each discrete time step, each square that is adjacent (sharing an edge) to one or more infected squares becomes infected with probability $p$. Infected squares stay infected forever.

Let $X_t$ be the number of squares infected at time $t$. It is probably far too complicated and difficult to explicitly calculate $\mathbb E[X_t]$. However, we can anticipate that $X_t\sim c\cdot t^2$ for some constant $c$ that depends on $p$. Does anyone know how to make this asymptotic estimate sharper by calculating the explicit value of $c$ in terms of $p$? In other words, can we find
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\mathbb E[X_t]}{t^2}=c=\space ?$$
I do know that $c=2$ when $p=1$ and $c=0$ when $p=0$, so I would expect something like $c=2p$ or $c=2p^2$. However, I have no idea how to go about finding $c$. Can somebody please help?

Comment: Can you clarify a few things? By adjacent, do you mean sharing an edge or does sharing a corner count too? Also, does an infected square stay infected for the next step or does it require an adjacent node and positive p-coin flip to say infected? Generally speaking, I would look in the contact processes and threshold processes literature for results on this. Depending on your answer to what you mean by adjacent, you should be able to find some results on $Z^2. $

Comment: @YacoubKureh Sorry for the ambiguity! Adjacent means edge-adjacent, and infection cannot spread to diagonally-adjacent squares (sharing a vertex). Once it is infected, a square stays infected forever. If someone posts an answer, I’m hoping to be able to use whatever method he/she uses to generalize and find an answer for other plane tilings (like hexagonal and triangular tessellations, for example) as well.

Comment: @Frpzzd: For an uninfected square with at least one adjacent infected square, is the probability of being infected in the next round equal to $p$ regardless of how many adjacent squares are infected?

Comment: @quasi That is correct.

Answer (score 6):

**New Answer.** This model is called *Richardson growth model*.

Richardson proved in $[2]$ that, for each $p \in (0, 1)$, there exists a norm $\varphi_p$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that the infected cluster at time $t$, normalized by time $t$, is asymptotically the unit ball with respect to $\varphi_p$. In particular, this shows that

$$ \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{\mathbb{E}[X_t]}{t^2} = \operatorname{Area}(\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \varphi_p(x) \leq 1\}) $$

is the area of the unit ball with respect to $\varphi_p$. In $[1]$, Durrett and Liggett provided further discussions by relating this model to the *first-passage percolation* with passage times distributed as $\operatorname{Geom}(p)$.

**References.**

- $[1]$ Durrett, R. and Liggett, T. (1981). The shape of the limit set in Richardson’s growth model. *Annals of Probab.*, **9**, 186–193.
- $[2]$ Richardson, D. (1973). Random growth in a tessellation. *Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc.*, **74**, 515–528.

---

**Old Answer.** Here are some simulations of the values $c = c(p)$ using the grid of size $1000\times1000$ and $500$ steps together with some fitting curves.

$\hspace{8em}$[image: Figure 1]

The data clearly deviates from the polynomial $2p^2$, and although the above plot may seem to suggest that $c(p)$ assumes a nice closed form, I believe that it is some artifact of numerical fitting and I am prone to believe that $c(p)$ is not given in a nice closed form in $p$. Also, using the same grid and number of steps, for $p = 1/2$, the cluster looks like

$\hspace{12em}$[image: Wolff shape]

The boundary is surprisingly smooth when compared to other well-known cluster growth models. And what is more surprising to me is that I was unable to find literature on this specific model. Perhaps I am simply missing the right keyword, but if it is the case that this model has yet been studied, even proving that $X_t$ typically grows at the speed of $\asymp t^2$ almost surely will make a very interesting result, letting alone scaling limit statement on the shape of the cluster.

Comment: That’s interesting. Any chance of finding the equation of the curve that this cluster seems to approximate? I find it very hard to believe that this problem hasn’t been considered before; surely there must be some literature about it...

Comment: Just another idea: perhaps it would be easier to asymptotically estimate the *distance* in the vertical/horizontal/diagonal directions that the growth covers by time $t$? This should be asymptotically linear...

Comment: It will be a fuzzy boundary , as the probability of infection increases from zero to nearly 1.

Comment: @SangchulLee Do you think there is any chance of finding a differential equation that models this smooth-ish curve?

Comment: @Frpzzd, It turns out to be a very hard problem, and despite many serious attempts, almost nothing seems known for the limiting shape to date. An exception is that Durrett-Liggett showed some flat-edge result on the limiting shape, see Theorem 9 of $[1]$ above.

Answer (score 0):

Some *extremely rough* estimates / possible approach / too long for a comment

It seems $c$ goes as $p^2$.

- Following OP, let $X_t$ be the no. of infected cells at time $t$.  This is a sort of "area".  $X_1 = 1$.
- Let $B_t$ be the no of non-infected cells which are next to some infected cells.  This is a sort of "boundary" or "circumference" of the "area" $X_t$.  $B_1 = 4$.
- By the infection model, $X_{t+1} - X_t = p B_t$.

We need another relation between $X$ and $B$ before attempting to solve.  It seems plausible that $B^2 \propto X$.  Lets say $B^2 = k X$.  What is $k$?

- If $X$ were a perfect $45^\circ$ tilted-square (such as when $p=1$), we would have $k=8$.
- If $X$ were a perfect square with sides parallel to the axes, we would have $k=16$.
- If $X$ were a circle, we would have (I'm not sure...) maybe $k = {(2\pi r)^2 \over \pi r^2} = 4\pi$.

We now have enough to plug in $X_t = c t^2$ and solve for $c$:

- $X_{t+1} - X_t = c ( (t+1)^2 - t^2) = c(2t+1) \approx 2ct$
- $pB_t = p \sqrt{kX} = p \sqrt{kc} \;t$
- Equating them: $2ct = p\sqrt{kc}\; t \implies \sqrt{c} = p\sqrt{k/4} \implies c = p^2 k/4$.

So if the tilted-square $(k=8)$ case is typical, we have $c = 2 p^2$.

Further thoughts: this is of course extremely rough.  Moreover, I believe there is one systemic bias: I believe $k=8$ is actually the minimal value for $k$, i.e. for *any* shape (any set of infected cells) $B^2 / X \ge 8$, with equality iff the shape is a perfect tilted square (which is guaranteed when $p=1$).  If so, maybe we can argue that $c=2p^2$ is in fact a rough lower bound?

Answer (score 0):

When $p$ is small, the leading-order probability that a cell $(\pm x,\pm y)$ is infected is $${x+y\choose x}{t\choose x+y}p^{x+y}\\ \approx {(tp)^{x+y}\over x!y!}$$ 
If I count the points where this approximation is greater than $1$, that implies that, for small $p$, the region is bounded by the curve $$tp=\sqrt[|x|+|y|]{|x|!|y|!}$$
Unfortunately, the contour plot of that function has an indent at $y=0$, which is not seen in Sanchul Lee's image.
[[image: Contour of <span class=]$\sqrt[x+y]{x!y!}$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26x3R.jpg)

Comment: Perhaps this is because Sanchul Lee used $p=1/2$, which may or may not count as “small p” for your purposes.